# What does “there” mean in the last sentence?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, grammaticality, verbs

> Nakata silently stood up and came over to stand in front of Miss Saeki. He
> laid his hard, sunburned hands on top of hers on the files. And as if listening
> carefully to something, *he felt the warmth **there** filter from her hand to his.*

I don’t know what “there” word means grammatically and why “filter” verb is used without suffix -s? It looks like “The warmth filters from her hand to his”.
I hope you help!

Comment: It is not the best of written passages.  Presumably, before this it has already been established that her hand is on the files.  In the sentence that follows, 'there' would naturally refer back to the very last thing:  the files!  It is physiologically obvious that heat must be passing from her hand to his, not from the files.  But this makes the writing at best clumsy, and needlessly so, since the files need not be mentioned.  The word 'filter' is not the best choice, I agree.  'Radiate' is what heat does.  So it is inept, but not incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it appears you are reading it correctly.

"There" appears to refer back to "hers" which refers back to his...sunburned hands." So the warmth is there, in her hands, and it filters (moves as if through a membrane) to his hands.

There is a subtle inconsistency too: "hers" refers to "hands" (plural), but the warmth filters from her "hand" (singular) to his.

Comment: You opened me a new door to English understanding! Thank you so much. This answer very helped me!

Comment: Please mark it as an accepted answer if you can. That will show others that the answer was OK. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't agree with the preceding answer and I think that the adverb "there" in this context is to be given the meaning in [OALD, 4](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/there_1?q=therehttps://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/there_1?q=there), that is,

- "at that point (in a story, an argument, etc.)".

If we were to replace this adverb by an equivalent we would then write

- "And as if listening carefully to something, he felt at that moment the warmth filter from her hand to his."

*or*

- "And as if listening carefully to something, he felt the warmth  then filter from her hand to his.".

"Filter" is used without an s because it is not the main verb in the verbal form and it is in fact an infinitive form (not conjugated, s is meaningless then). the verbal form is "**to feel sth do sth** ([OALD, 2](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/feel_1?q=feel)).

- feel somebody/something/yourself do something
  I felt something crawl up my arm.
  We felt the ground give way under our feet.

Comment: Thank you for links!

Answer (score 0):

> he felt the warmth there filter from her hand to his

In the sentence, *there* pinpoints where his hands engaged in physical contact with her hand.

> why “filter” verb is used without suffix -s?

There is a verb pattern *hear, see, etc. + object + infinitive or -ing*.

One can use either the infinitive without *to* or the -*ing* form after the object of verbs such as *see*, *hear*.

The infinitive without *to* refers to the whole event someone hears or sees.

For example, "I saw him go." I observed the whole event.

The -*ing* form refers to an event that is in progress.

For example, "She heard them talking." The event was happening, not completed.

In your example, the person observed the whole *filter* event.